# Filtering out maybe types before accessing nullable property

Tags: flowtype

Given these two types:

```
type Point = [
  number,
  number,
];

type Some = {
  a: Point,
  b: ?Point,
};
```

And the data set:

```
const somes: Array<Some> = [
  {a: [0, 1], b: [0, 2]}, 
  {a: [2, 3], b: null}
]
```

Flow will automatically fail if we try to access `somes[n].b.x` given that b is a maybe type and might be either null or undefined.

We can however with confidence filter out all items in `somes` to exclude any item that does not include `b`:

```
const withB = somes.filter(s => !!s.b)
```

However flowtype will still complain when accessing items in `withB` as it doesn't pick up the exclusion:

```
console.log( withB.map(s => s.b[0]).join(',') )
// console.log(withB.map(s => s.b[0]).join(','))
//                              ^^^^^^ access of computed property/element. // Computed property/element cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value
// console.log(withB.map(s => s.b[0]).join(','))
//                            ^^^ undefined
```

Is it possible to somehow annotate or hint to flow that all items in `withB` are now guaranteed to include the `b` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option if you are willing to pay for additional computations

```
const withB = somes
  .map(x => x.b ? { a: x.a, b: x.b } : null)
  .filter(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general way to hint Flow anything:

```
 const withB: Array<{ a: Point, b: Point }> = (somes.filter(s => !!s.b): any)
```

It won't be safe in your case though. You have an array of mutable objects and property `'b'` can be set to `null` at any time.

Comment: Thanks @vkurchatkin! I'll be happy to mark this as correct if there's no more elegant way :)